# Problems accessing Google extension function from another extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As the title states, is it possible to access the methods defined in a google extension from another google extension?  The method I am trying to access can be called from the Google Console, however, when I try to access the method from my background page with the following code

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(ns.tracsCopyFromTabId, {
            code: "alert(methodName)"  
        }
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension
```

I believe the method I'm trying to access is defined in their content-script?  Has anyone ever tried and successfully do this?

Comment: Did you need to change the console's context (above) to the extension's name to call the code?

Comment: Hi Xan, no I didn't need to change the context.  I typed only the method name in the console and it worked.

Comment: Also, this error looks fishy. Unless there's `allFrames: true` involved, you may be injecting in the wrong tab? As in, not in a regular webpage (where _content scripts_ would be)?

Comment: But even if I were in the right tab, wouldn't their content script be inaccessible unless I have the proper permissions and then their script injected?

Comment: I'm still not certain you're calling the code a _content script_ correctly. Because then you'd only be able to call it by changing the context from `top` to the extension name. But assuming you are, a content script won't be accessible, period, as it's an isolated JS context.

Comment: You'd need to whip out `debugger` + possibly customize Chrome flags to access that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure 100% it's a content script either.  If it's not from a content script then what else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

### The error

The error + your comment about not needing to change the context signifies that you're **probably** not *actually* injecting in a regular webpage that runs content scripts, but into an extension page (with visible URL `chrome-extension://...`).

Anything in such a page is *not* a content script by definition. Even if that code is *also* shared with a content script used somewhere else.

Note that if you're using (but not showing) `allFrames: true` for injection, you may be accidentally injecting in an extension-page frame, leading to that error.

### Non-content script code

The problem is that you can't declare host permissions for `chrome-extension://` pages. Therefore you can't inject content scripts into those pages.

It's not possible to define permissions to do that from an extension alone (to make an extension you can distribute that "just works"), but you can do it locally with Chrome flags + [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger).

You will need `chrome://flags/#silent-debugger-extension-api` enabled and will need to use the [Debugger Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to execute your code.

Sadly, the `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` flag does not allow injection into this protocol either, so you *have* to use Debugger.

### Content script code

If you're actually trying to reach code in a content script in a regular webpage, you can't call it from your own content script because every extension gets its own isolated JS context.

You'd need `chrome.debugger` again.

### Code injected in the page context

Sometimes you're dealing with code that's [injected in the webpage itself from a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script).

Then you should be able to access it with the method you describe by making the same content script -> page code leap. See the link above.

That doesn't explain the error you're getting though.

Comment: okay it's giving me the same error "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running debugger.attach: Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension".  I used the code below in my background page

Comment: chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:ns.tracsCopyFromTabId}, "Runtime.evaluate", {expression:"methodName"}, function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });

Comment: Did you toggle the flag AND restarted the browser?

Comment: You'd also need the `"<all_urls>"` permission, I think.

Comment: i added "<all_urls>" and same error.  I also toggled the flag and restarted  :/

Comment: Then someone needs to dig further. It used to work at some point, but it's conceivable that they have closed this possibility out of security concerns, like they did with webRequest interception.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will let you know if I find the solution.